# How do I differentiate between direct and indirect object with an object of a preposition present?

Tags: transitivity, direct-objects, indirect-objects, prepositional-objects

I am working on the following sentence:

- *They will look toward me, whom they pierced*.

I am aware that a basic rule to identifying an indirect object is to ask, "to whom?" However, in this case, I am confused since the entire verbal idea is "to look toward [with confidence]".

Two questions:

- Is *me* the direct object, the indirect object, or the object of the preposition?
- Is *to look toward* a transitive or intransitive verb?

Comment: If this is a Bible translation [John 19:37], I'm puzzled: I can't find any _look toward/s_'s, just one _look to_ (Young's L T) which could have idiomatic force, and just possibly be treated as a multi word verb, but mainly _look on ..._'s, a now rare variant of _gaze on ..._. Plus some modern  _look at_ 's. If the verb is used literally, it is simplex.

Comment: It is my own translation from the Hebrew of Zechariah 12:10b (also quoted in John 19:37). The Hebrew verb being used often occurs with the preposition to express the idea of looking on/toward someone with confidence (e.g., Isaiah 22:8; Jonah 2:4; Psalm 34:5).

Comment: While I wouldn't say that this is in any way promoting wrong doctrine, it is not a correct interpretation of these particular Scriptures. Context shows that the onlookers have a spirit of contrition and mourning at this point, not confident dependence. The verb _look_ is used in its literal or near-literal sense, nothing like the usage in say 'I look to thee for strength' (Massachusetts Missionary Magazine ..., Volume 3) It's almost always best to use Scriptures in the ways expositors usually do, to avoid criticism by those who will find technical faults.

Comment: I understand your point (Thanks!), but was only following the category given by the lexicographers in the Hebrew and Aramaic Lexicon of the Old Testament, for the sake of argument. My translation was only trying to stress my confusion, namely, if some verbs appear with certain prepositions, often to form an idiomatic combination, then is "to look to/on/toward" to be taken as a whole verbal idea? In my current work I translate it simply as, "they will look to me, whom..."

Comment: Moreover, some Hebrew grammars differentiate between an object of a preposition and an indirect object, while others say they are the same thing. Also, the Oxford English Dictionary seems to state that the verb "look" is normally intransitive, but then goes on to present it as transitive in other cases. Just trying to get my head around this.

Comment: Right. The whole treatment of what some call the 'phrasal verb vs verb + prepositional phrase' debate is far from easy, and certainly not agreed upon. Even the terminologies are chaotic. Obviously, some verb + whatsit combinations (eg 'he _looked after_ the dog') are closely bound and arguably best treated as single entities (I use the term multi-word verbs). Other expressions are obviously simplex verb + prepositional phrase (eg 'he _ran_ across the bridge'). But there are many harder to classify (eg 'she died of pneumonia'). Much has been written on these issues.

Comment: [Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/look-to) treats 'look to' in the sense you mean as a MWV (though they use the ambiguous term 'phrasal verb') and use 'transitive' to show the MWV takes what they term a direct object, in a similar way to a simplex verb: **look to** PHRASAL VERB [TRANSITIVE]

1 _look to_  (someone) to hope or expect to get help, advice etc from someone //  _look to_ (someone for something): As young children, we looked to our parents for guidance. // _look to_ (someone to do something): They’re looking to me to help improve sales figures.

Comment: Over the years, I've collected about 60 articles addressing the issue of MWVs vs Verb + Prepositional Phrase constructions. The tests for coherence between simplex-or-whatever verb and particle-or-whatever do not always tally; it's best to see how these things are actually used on an individual basis, and use them in the same way. Reading individual grammars will almost certainly result in confusion.

Answer (score 2):

"me" is object of the preposition "toward" and is not a direct object (but see below) or an indirect object.  "to look toward" is not a verb, but rather a combination of the verb "look" and the preposition "toward".  A way to identify a verb is to see whether it can be inflected as other verbs can.  If "look toward" were a verb, you'd expect a past tense form "look towarded", but of course that's not possible.

On the other hand, a way to identify a transitive verb and a direct object is to try forming a passive construction making the original direct object the subject of the passive.  Here, that gets us "I was looked toward", which sounds pretty good.  It is called a prepositional passive construction.  So maybe there is a sense in which "look toward" is a transitive verb and "me" is its direct object.  I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

"Me" is the object of the preposition "toward," and also the antecedent of "whom." "Whom" is the direct object of "pierced."
"To look" is the verb, not "to look toward." "To look" is intransitive.